# Regex in chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I need to add some Regex inside my chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher.

So far I have

```
var matcher = new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
    pageUrl: {
         urlContains: "something.com/someRegex/something"

    }
 });
```

Essentially I want to have a regular expression to evaluate to "something.com/4-5 char string/somithing".

How would I do this? Is this possible to do with chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the RegEx would be: `something\.com/[^/]{4,5}/something`. It means any substring that isnt a "/" and is 4-5 characters in length. You also have to escape `.` since it is a metacharacter and means "any character".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of **urlContains** use **urlMatches**

This is what I'm using for both domain fedmich.com and fedche.com

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlMatches: '(fedmich|fedche)\.com' },
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

documentation is here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#property-UrlFilter-hostEquals

The regular expressions use the RE2 syntax.
https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax

Answer (score 0):

In https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#property-UrlFilter-hostEquals it describes urlMatches case.

Comment: Link-only answers are [considered bad at Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @Xan but you can see by the user's points they are new. Marking them down for it is also considered bad.